# Why does check_ajax_referer give a 403 error on https websites?

Tags: ajax, security, https, nonce

When I write an ajax funtion on a site without SSL, check_ajax_referer works as intended.
But it fails with a 403 forbidden error on a https site. I've tried a lot of times, but I just don't know why it doesn't work.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Form (widget class):

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ){
    $action = '?action=registration';
    $unique_string = "Unique string";
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce($unique_string);
        
    wp_localize_script('registration_script', 'registration_ajax_object',
        array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . $action,
            'nonce' => $nonce
        )
    );
    ?>
    ...form...
    <?php
}
```

Main plugin file:

```
function ajax_registration(){
    check_ajax_referer('Unique string', 'nonce');
    ...
}
add_action('wp_ajax_registration', 'ajax_registration');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_registration', 'ajax_registration');
```

JS file:

```
let ajaxurl = registration_ajax_object.ajaxurl;
let nonce = registration_ajax_object.nonce;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'nonce': nonce,
        ...
    }, ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

that looks good in my eyes. but i just had the same issue, that's why i stumbled over your question.

i fixed it in my case with

```
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'nonce')) {
    die(__('Security Check failed', 'textdomain'));
}
```

at the very beginning of my ajax action. no idea, where the 403 issue came from, since it worked on desktop machines, but not on my mobile. weird.. give it a shot and let me know, if this helps.

one other thing i saw in your code, but not sure, if it is causing issues: one time you use single quotes, the other time doubles. try to be consistent here.

[wp_verify_nonce()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_verify_nonce/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've arrived at the same conclusion. On https sites you **have to** use wp_verify_nonce() and NOT check_ajax_referer(). You can do it as a one-liner: `wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'Unique string');`
Illogical, but that's how it is. I did not see any difference between desktop and mobile though. Quotes are consistent in my files, it's just an oversight while using the stackoverflow editor.
Edit: But we still don't know **why** it works like this.

Comment: i just figured out, that caching also might be an issue! when you use some kind of template caching, you most certainly also cache your nonces. at least this explains my issue with desktop/mobile. so i now told my caching tool to recreate cache every 8hours. was 10, but i had issues with that setting.

Comment: Yeah, I can see why caching may cause inconsistencies. I always test without it though. What tool do you use for it? Does it make a good difference in loading times?

Comment: i always used w3tc, it is good. but i had issues with minify. so i switched to wp rocket. not super happy with it..